# Tying Ruby classes to timeframes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activerecord

I've got a rails app with models which occur on a weekly basis. Put another way, every user has an instance of the model (let's say it's GroceryList) generated once weekly on Monday morning. I'd like to integrate some syntactic sugar into my GroceryList model so that I can easily reference past lists using ruby-esque syntax, perhaps as below:

```
current_user.grocery_list.1.week.ago
```

As it stands, each GroceryList item has a created_on date, of course, as well as a start_date which indicates the beginning of the week (Monday).

Is there an established way of tying this type of functionality into a ruby class, and if so how does one achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with `current_user.grocery_list(1.week.ago)` and defining a method to do so (obviously naming is up to you)?

Comment: Something like this? 

`current_user.list_from(1.week.ago)`

in user.rb:

`def list_from(timeframe)
  list.where(:start_date => timeframe)
end`  Nothing I suppose, I'm just not sure if that's the best practice. I'm quite happy with that simple a solution, as long as I'm not ignoring some obvious idiom I should be employing.

Comment: IMO, making a method that takes a date and returns what you want is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of thing is pretty easy to add with named scopes:

```
class GroceryList < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :from, lambda { |date|
    where(:created_on => date.to_date)
  }
end
```

Then you can fetch through any relationship using something simple like:

```
current_user.grocery_list.from(1.week.ago)
```

Comment: Note that this is no different than `def self.from(date); where(:create_on => date.to_date); end`. Also, `when` is a keyword so you can't use it as a variable name like that.

Comment: You're right about the keyword. I've always thought that declaring a `scope` is better than a class method even if it involves a `lambda` since it shows up better when you're reflecting on things like available scopes.